# rviz global options target frame is missing in groovy

Tags: ros, rviz, frame, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the urg Hokuyo laserscanner node, which needs the /laser frame. In http://answers.ros.org/question/10655/fixed-frame-laser-does-not-exist/ it is suggested to use the /laser target frame in order to make it work. The target frame option in Groovy's rviz is missing, perhaps it uses an other solution I don't know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60458/rviz-global-options-target-frame-is-missing-in-groovy/) by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will find this under *Fixed Frame* under *Global Options* in the *Displays* Panel.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-04-11**:
Yes I am aware of that, but I am looking for the "target frame". It was present in the Fuerte version and in Grovvy it is missing.

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-04-12**:
This is in the "Views" panel.